# How to manage multiple content scripts on the same page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a small chrome extension and need to have the overall content script and some detailed version on some subpages. I have two ready scripts but the overall one doesn't works on detailes subpages :/

```
http://example.org/* - overall works, special is offline   
http://example.org/otherpage* - overall works, special is offline  
http://example.org/special* - overall doesn't works (why?), special works



"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "http://example.org/*" ],
      "js": [ "overall.js", "jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ]
    },
    {
      "matches": [ "http://example.org/special*" ],
      "js": [ "special.js", "jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ],
    }
  ]
```

I tried start like that but it doesn't help

```
 "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [ "http://example.org/special*" ],
          "js": [ "overall.js","overall.js", "jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ]
        },
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is too vague. The script itself should run (unless there's a bug in Chrome) which you can verify by examining the scripts in devtools -> sources -> [content scripts panel](https://puu.sh/DPOJG/6af5d41e6f.png).